# How can the category and product fields in Shopizer be customized, if possible at all?

Tags: shopizer

I am currently using [Shopizer](https://github.com/shopizer/shopizer.github.com) as a sort of headless CMS, leveraging its out of the box admin pages and REST API for the content. There is a page for editing products in the admin system but I would like to add and/or remove specific fields. Making changes to the base code seems to be the most obvious solution but it is taking me a significant amount of time to implement it successfully.

Is there some sort of a config file or an initialization process to customize the fields for creating categories and products using Shopizer's admin page? What is the best practice for this scenario if the former approach is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add fields the easiest way is to add them in model objects
com.salesmanager.core.model.*

Example of an annotated field

```
@Column (name ="IP_ADDRESS")
private String ipAddress;
```

Once you restart your instance the new field will be available.

Comment: @JD Hernandez this is the answer. It would be helpful to the community if you accept.